# Boot Camp install of Windows 10 gets stuck on first logo and spinner

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I follow all the steps of the official documentation https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468 . I have a MacBook Pro 2016 with macOS High Sierra. The computer restarts automatically and attempts to boot into the windows setup.

As soon as the screen below shows up, the computer seems to freeze. The dotted progress spinner does not spin. I've waited for hours and nothing happens.

After I forcefully shutdown and restart into macOS, I can see that the partition was created fine.

[image: Photo of MacBook at Windows boot screen]

### Edit with output of diskutil list

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         134.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                116.7 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +134.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            39.9 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 19.9 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                520.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

Comment: You can start by opening the Terminal application and entering the command `diskutil list`.  Post the output to your question. This command will not change your computer.

Comment: Can I assume the BOOTCAMP volume is empty?

Comment: If you restart your Mac and hold down the option key, you will get the Startup Manager. I assume if you do this, you will not find an icon label either "EFI boot" or "Windows". Also, can I assume you did not need a flash drive to install Windows?

Comment: The windows drive actually was there, turns out the freezing was due to having an external gpu attached.

Answer (score 2):

So turns out the problem *for me* is booting up with an external gpu attached. In the photo you can see the little thunderbolt cable on the left. Even though it works fine booting into macOS, it doesn't work when booting up into windows for some reason.

This freeze happens even after the Windows OS is installed. The workaround is to unplug the egpu and re-attach post bootup.

For anyone else coming across this, my egpu is a mantiz venus w/ rx 570.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.. I had a major problem attempting to boot up with a USB flash drive attached.  Removing that drive (based on this answer) gave me success... thx again.

Comment: thats.... incredible. Why should that ever be a problem. Apple...

Comment: My problem was a bit different. With a USB flash drive plugged in to the MacBook I could no longer use the option key to control the boot up process. No matter what I did the unit would ONLY boot to the bootcamp Windows partition. I wasn’t able to boot up MacOS until the USB drive was removed.

Comment: i'm not sure what it was but i unplugged all my usbc connectors (usb hub, multipe drives, iot cards) on my macbookpro and it finally worked. the clue was in these comments.

Comment: Damn, I spent a lot of time finding this.